# How to check if a function input is given or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function

Please consider this function that accepts two arguments: `series` and `categorical_values`. Its goal is to get a `series`, make it categorical, and then print each element of the original series alongside the categorized corresponding element. However, if the `categorical_values`  is already passed to the function as an input, the categorization stage is skipped and the function simply prints the pairs of the passed `series` and `categorical_values`.

```
def my_function(series, categorical_values = None):

    if categorical_values: #meant to mean "if this argument is passed, just use it"
        categorical_values = categorical_values

    else: #meant to mean "if this argument is not passed, create it"
        categorical_values= pd.qcut(series, q = 5)

    for i,j in zip(series, categorical_values):
        print(i, j)
```

However, passing `categorical_values` in the following:

```
my_function(series, pd.qcut(series, q = 5))
```

leads to:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The code line where this error results from is the very first line: `if categorical_values:`

What is the proper way to check if a function argument has been passed or is not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the default is None, you should just check it is not that.

```
if categorical_values is not None:
    ...
```

But that if block is a no-op anyway; it would be better to reverse it:

```
if categorical_values is None:
    categorical_values = pd.qcut(series, q = 5)
```

and you don't need an else block at all.

Comment: Dang it. I even tried `categorical_values != None`. Now I see how it should be `categorical_values is not None` instead, as in the former case it tried to compare each element in `categorical_values` to `None`, thus throwing that error. Thanks

Comment: @Saeed This is one of the reasons why you’re supposed to use `is` instead of `==` with `None`. Besides the stylistic and performance issues, which are pretty minor, classes can override `==` to return, say, an array of bools, which can’t be used in an if condition.